# Identifying Angular component instances by a unique ID

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm working on an Angular application where I created a component called TripSummaryComponent that I'm using for showing trips informations this way :

```
<div *ngFor="let trip of trips">
    <trip-summary [trip]="trip"></trip-summary>
</div>
```

[image]
Now my need is: how to identify each instance of TripSummaryComponent by a unique id after it's generated in the DOM.

Thank's in advance for helping.

Comment: What do you need that for? In Angular, one generally doesn't access components by ID, but instead injects a reference to the component directly.

Comment: @meriton can you please explain more, with an example if possible ?

Comment: Can you answer my question first? Because the answer depends on what you want to use the ID for.

Comment: It would be better if you provided information on what your are trying to achieve - as someone using Angular on a regular basis, the idea to identify components by ids seems fishy to me. Maybe there is a better approach!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend passing an ID via an input to the child component. Why not directly creating one in the child component itself via an UUID generator (which you need to provide with a third party library, e.g. [uuid generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)):

#### Component

```
readonly id: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = uuid.v4();
}
```

#### Template

```
<div [attr.id]="id">
  <!-- rest of the template -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: Of course I really don't recommend to this. But It can be done.

Use `ViewChildren` and `QueryList`

> Identify each instance of TripSummaryComponent

Add an `idGenerator()` that always return unique id

> by a unique id

Inside ngAfterViewInit()

> after it's generated in the DOM.

#### Requirements

Add `id` input to trip-summary component

```
@Input() trip
@Input() id
```

#### Get trip-summary component references

Use `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` to have all components refences.

```js
@ViewChildren(TestComponent) testQueryList: QueryList<TestComponent>;

  trip = [
    { id: "1", name: "one" },
    { id: "2", name: "two" },
    { id: "3", name: "three" }
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testQueryList.forEach(component => console.log(component));
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

#### Add unique id to trip-summary components inside ngAfterViewInit

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.testQueryList.forEach((component, index) => component.id = this.generateUniqueId());
}

private generateUniqueId(): string {
  return 'here should return unique id'
}
```

#### Result

Each instance of components has unique id

**Working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r6qlkm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Assigning component state in a parent components afterViewInit() is brittle, because the state of that component has already been change detected, resulting in an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in development mode, or a stale value in the DOM in production mode.

Comment: ... as you can see if your open the error console in the stackblitz you posted.

Comment: Yes.! It needs to be updated by detectChanges(). Thanks!